# Run asynchronous tasks on outlook start up

Tags: c#, asynchronous, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have an outlook add in that contains one form , there are 6 web-service calls should be executed on form load to get binding data and these calls make the load for frame too slow.

how can I run these calls (asynchronously) for one time on outlook start up and cache the returned data on memory during outlook life cycle?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a secondary thread(s)? Just keep in mind that whatever you need from Outlook, must be retrieved on the primary thread.

Comment: Ok, but how to run these threads on outlook start up and cache the retrieved data in memory?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what the problem is. What programming language are you using?